# Wrap with span if text is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following function to wrap highlighted text with a `<span>` when the backspace/delete key is hit.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  typoNumber++;
  if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.setAttribute('id', 'typo' + typoNumber);
    span.className = "deleted typo";
    span.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
    if (window.getSelection) {
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        range.surroundContents(span);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.deleted.typo {
  background: rgba(100,100,100,0.25);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Here is text to experiment with.</div>
```

I only want the function to run if there is text selected (so that I don't get a bunch of empty `<span>` elements). I tried changing the first `if` statement to the following:

```
 if (selection !== '' && event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) {
```

but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your condition to this should help you:

```
if(
  selection.anchorOffset !== selection.focusOffset 
  && 
  (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)
)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34L49xLr/

Comment: That did it. Thanks, @rorymorris89!

Answer (score 0):

`getSelection` actually returns an object (a [SelectionObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)) - you can convert that to a string and then check its length to determine whether or not there's any text selected. Something like this:

```js
// Make sure you're initializing this somewhere; this function expects it defined.
var typoNumber = 0;

$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  var selection = document.getSelection();

  // If there's nothing selected, bail out here.
  // If you want to increment typoNumber even with an empty selection,
  // move that line above this block.
  if (selection.toString().length < 1) {
    return;
  }

  typoNumber++;
  if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.setAttribute('id', 'typo' + typoNumber);
    span.className = "deleted typo";
    span.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
    if (window.getSelection) {
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        range.surroundContents(span);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* so we can see where the spans are... */
.deleted.typo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  background: rgba(100,100,100,0.25);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Here is text to experiment with.</div>
```